# Loop through array models in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection and I'm getting the models based on a property like this

```
var coll=reportWidgets.where({"is_editing":true});
```

I want to loop through these models and set the property `is_editing` to false.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_.each(reportWidgets.where({is_editing: true}), function (reportWidget) {
  reportWidget.set('is_editing', false);
});
```

An alternative using `_.invoke` similar to @nikoshr

```
_.invoke(reportWidgets.where({is_editing: true}), 'set', 'is_editing', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

A different take on the problem, using [`_.chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) and [`_.invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke) for fun and, I hope, readability

```
reportWidgets.chain().filter(function(m) {
    return m.get('is_editing');
}).invoke('set', 'is_editing', false);
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/PMvLC/

Note that in that context using `where` would produce unexpected results since it would work on an array of models and not on a collection and its proxied underscore methods.